# UI of Product Listing Based on Screen Size

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am using magento (html, php, js) and want to design the product listing page to change based on screen size. The current design is responsive, however, I need to use Cards in large screens, and something else completely different than cards in small screens. Products are in array/collection and I have a for loop to display product attributes. I am looking for something other than css media queries such as

If screen is small
// display list
Else
//use cards

Is there a method in php to detect screen size?is it a good practice to use it? What if browser view resized?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is only achievable with **javascript** or **css**. PHP is  a server-side language and is compiled *before* it reaches the client. This means that the PHP script does not know *anything* about your client's computer/browser without using HTTP protocols.

The most practical solution for this scenario would be to use media queries since they are the most supported amongst browsers. In fact, they are very simple to use. In the example below, open the snippet in full page, resize the window, and observe how the two boxes respond to the size of the screen:

```css
/* Standard Appearace */

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}


/* Mobile Appearance */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}




/* Ignore: Irrelevant CSS */

.box {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.box:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
```

If you *really* want to stay away from media queries, you could use `window.availWidth` to get the width of the window, from where you can write `if` statements to adjust your content.